# Solr sort different criteria for each subset

Tags: apache, sorting, solr

We are using Apache SOLR for full text search. We have specific requirement for sorting the search results - basically when querying for data, we need 2 sets of data - A and B, but each set should have its own sorting criteria and we cannot make 2 different calls. We can get 2 sets by using an OR condition, but how do we sort each set differently ? To illustrate, if :

Set A = {3,1,2}
 Set B = {8,5,9}

So, the expected response can have set A returned in ascending order {1,2,3} but the set B can be returned in descending order {9,8,5}

I believe the default sort in SOLR will sort the entire results sets. Any suggestions or if the question is not clear,let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly achieve this using [FieldCollapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing)

You might need to do a little more work - i.e. have a display order field(could be an integer) so that Solr knows one field that it needs to sort by.

Next you could use a query like this -

```
&q=*&group=true&group.field=set&group.sort=display_order
```

I would recommend keeping the logic such as this out of Solr, it isn't meant to be a substitute for Relational Databases, and getting it to do complex SQL like operation (while some are possible) is going to be tricky.

By the way there is an [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1093) in Solr's JIRA that addresses batch processing of multiple queries. Which means, when it is merged into a release, you could fire n different queries to fetch these sets in one call to Solr.

If you are keen to have SOLR perform this task for you, the patch is available in the JIRA card, you could create a build for yourself and let us all know how it goes :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I guess, I should have mentioned this earlier so here's the deal - patching solr in not in our control. Additionally, we cannot keep a display order field because sorting order is bit dynamic based on  a date field, so if a date has expired i.e if current date is greater than the date set in the field then the document moves from 1st set to 2nd set.

Comment: Any more help/suggestions ?

Comment: Looks like you have a fair bit of domain logic in Solr - I don't think Solr should be used as a data store in this manner. The only possibility that comes to mind is to have `group.sort` use a [Function Query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Date_Boosting) and do some manipulation

Comment: I think it would be good if you can reconsider the design, and talk to the folks responsible for these decisions. If you move documents from Set to Set, what would happen during Re-indexing? The parent system will be unaware of this logic. It seems to add quite a bit of complexity here.